# IOS smooth transitions between controllers

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I've been wondering how many apps have very neat transitions to do "close up" to a picture or item. Is there some kind of framework or something? I have no idea of how they achieve something that nice and smooth without making a code mess. I have a collection view with a custom layout (ipad) and I want to present the item info when touched proceeding an animation like this:
[image]

If there's any guide or any tips to do something similar please let me know.

Comment: I would look up first how to present the image if its pushed from the CollectioNView. Then you could look up how to animate view transitions. If you try the code and you have problems you can always post what you got.

Comment: I was trying to find the official apple docs on custom View Controller Transitions. If someone finds them, plz 2 link.  But you'll want to look them up.  There's a couple of good tutorials out there, and this is a [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002636/uicollectionview-zoom-transition-like-ios7-calendar) which might help.